# Silex 500 error

Tags: mod-rewrite, silex

**index.php**

```
use Silex\Application;
require_once __DIR__ . './vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Application();
$app->run();
```

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

visiting

```
127.0.0.1/index.php
```

I get

> 500 internal error.

Any solutions please?

Comment: Look in your web server's error log where the 500 will be detailed more thoroughly.  You will probably find that you must `require_once` the autoloader _before_ attempting to `use Silex\Application;` because that namespace is undefined before the autoloader has been invoked. Follow the pattern [in the Silex docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)

Comment: Yes, but if i repair this, I got same error.

Comment: But problem is in loading autoload.php: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Well, that sounds like you need to correct file permissions on vendor/autoload.php.  Make sure it is readable by the Apache web server user.

Comment: Please, how can i check this?

Comment: That depends on your operating system. On a Unix system you would use `ls -l` to see permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your htaccess files should not be named `.htaccess.php` but just `.htaccess`.

Then make sure every files have the good rights (apache has access to it).

Be also sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled.